# Call javascript function multiple times with different json-array

Tags: php, javascript, function, unique

I got this code:

```
function datatable_display(json) {

    var order = "desc";

    var len = $('.div_gui_tabledata').length;
    len = len++;
    var table = $('#dynamic_' + len);

    document.write("<div class='div_gui_tabledata' id='dynamic_" + len + "' >");


    this.array = JSON.stringify(json);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../api.php?p=datatable_sort",
        data: "sortby=2&data=" + array,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#dynamic_' + len).html(data);
        }
    });

    document.write("</div>");


    $('#dynamic_' + len + ' .sortable').live("click", function () {

        var index = $(this).index();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../api.php?p=datatable_sort",
            data: "order=" + order + "&sortby=" + index + "&data=" + array,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#dynamic_' + len).html(data);
                if (order == "desc")
                    order = "asc";
                else
                    order = "desc";
            }
        });
    });

}
```

I call this function from my PHP-Script like that:

```
 $json = json_encode($this->arr);
 return "<script>datatable_display($json);</script></div>";
```

When I call the function twice or even more times, the problem is the json-Object Array is always overwritten by the last.

Is there something like OOP in Javascript? Or something that threatens each function call unique? I generate unique ids for the divs and the Sort-Links, but then only the latest JSON Object is used.

Comment: Jeah, that's really useful ... not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of architectural things you could be doing differently to make life a lot easier for yourself, but you're likely to discover these in time on your own. To answer your immediate question, using javascript's built-in objects should solve your problem.

```
var str = "something"; // choose your own key
this.store = {}
this.store[str] = JSON.stringify(json);
```

*or*

```
this.array = []; // in your initializer or constructor
this.array.push(JSON.stringify(json)); // this will add to the array as you go
```

In this way you can keep a history of json without overwriting what you had before.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it and it seems to work! Thanks!

Yes, these architectural things.. Do you have any examples of how I could improve the function ?